# Composite design pattern PHP example

Tags: php, design-patterns

In client code, and at it's very simplest it should read something like:

```
<?php
// Client code
 $int1 = new _Integer(2);
 $int2 = new _Integer(3);

 $operator = new Operator('+');

 $op1 = new Operands($int1);
 $op2 = new Operands($int2);

// $op1 + $operator + $op2 = Solution === 5

?>
```

However, we're attempting this using the composite design pattern and things soon become non-trivial. I have been working on the following:

```
<?php

// Use case: 2 + 3 = 5

// Component
interface Solution {
        function f();
}
// Composite
class Operands implements Solution {
        private $ints = [];
        function __construct(_Integer $_integer = null ){
                $this->_integer = $_integer; 
                array_push($this->ints, $this->_integer);
        }
        function f(){ /* Do nothing */ }

}
// Leaf
class _Integer implements Solution {
        private $_int;
        function __construct($_int){
                $this->_int = $_int;
        }
        function f(){ /* Do nothing */ }

        function getInt(){
                return $this->_int;
        }
}
// Leaf
class Operator implements Solution {
        private $operator;
        function __construct($operator){
            $valid = in_array($operator, ['+','-','/','*']);
            if($valid) $this->operator = $operator;
        }

        function f(){ /* Do nothing */ }
}
```

Ive reached a point where I need some help with Verbs and Nouns moreover the logic behind this great pattern - based around this simple equation.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: @PeeHaa. Admittedly, it was not very well defined. OK, I'm trying to apply the composite pattern to an arithmetic expression say:

((3 + 4 - 1) * 5 + 6 * -7) / 2

```
                  '/'
                /     \
              +        2
           /     \
         *         *
       /   \     /   \
      -     5   6     -7
    /   \
   +     1
 /   \
3     4
```

for example, in PHP. I first got the idea from:
https://sourcemaking.com/files/v2/content/patterns/Composite_example1-2x.png

but am struggling a little with it and was looking for some guidance.

Comment: Your code samples don't really make much sense? Also it isn't clear what your actual question is.

Comment: Try to revise your question a bit and try to ask a very clear question. Because patterns and the composite design pattern in particular aren't that easy to understand conceptually, so this could be a great Q&A tread if handled with care

Comment: $sum = new Operation("+", $op1, $op2); $minus = new Operation("-", $sum, new Operand(new _Integer(1));